# update or delete on table "users" violates foreign key constraint "fk_owner_id" on table "movie_list"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have problem deleting a user and cascading deletion to all his movie lists.

```
class User {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<MovieList> movieLists;
}

class MovieList {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_owner_id"))
    private User owner;
}
```

This is the method I call when trying to remove a user:

```
userRepository.delete(user);
```

When I try to delete a user, I get the following :

update or delete on table "users" violates foreign key constraint "fk_owner_id" on table "movie_list".

How can I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello i think you need add attributes in your anotation

Like this:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
```

In other words, it has to pass (CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)